# Are these two methods for obtaining the mid point equivalent?

Tags: fractions

I was working on computer science problem on LeetCode website.  The solution required that the midpoint be calculated between two numbers, lets call them `start` and `end`.  Ultimately my solution passed the tests.  The issue is that one of the other solutions I found had a similar solution, but it calculated the midpoint differently.

This is how I calculated it:  `mid = (start + end) / 2`
This is how the other solution calculated it:  `mid = start + (end - start) / 2`

Are these two functions equivalent? I tried to use my math skills, but they seem to have deteriorated over the decades. This is what I came up with so far, but just need some insight.
`(start + end) / 2 = start + (end - start) / 2`
`start + end = (start + (end - start)/2) * 2`
`start + end = 2 * start + (end - start)`
`start + end = start + end`

Comment: You can just expand out the second equation: $m=s+(e-s)/2=s-s/2+e/2=s/2+e/2=(s+e)/2$

Comment: The two formulas are mathematically equivalent, but may potentially produce different numeric results depending on the data types, precision and rounding modes. This, however, would no longer be a math question but a programming one.